# How does SQL Server handle large physical database file

Tags: sql, sql-server

Coming from MySQL and PostgreSQL, i would very much like to know how SQL Server stores and handles large physical database file.

According to this article here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174545%28SQL.80%29.aspx

SQL Server has 3 types of file, `.mdf`, `.ndf` and `.ldf`

Due to the nature of how data grows, a database can contain hundreds of thousand of files. This would eventually affect the size of these `.mdf`.

So the question is, how does SQL Server handle large physical database files?

I might seem to ask a lot of question, but i would like to have an answer also covers the sub-question below:

1. Theoretically, `.mdf` filesize could grow to GB or perhaps TB. Is this common in real world scenario?
2. Since SQL Server deals with a single file, it would have a considerably large read/write operation performed on the same file. How would this impact the performance?
3. Is it possible (has there been any case) to split `.mdf` into parts. Instead of having 1 uber large `.mdf` file, would it be better to split it into chunks?

note: I am new to SQL Server, basic query in SQL Server appears to be similar to MySQL, I would like to know a bit about what is going on "under the hood".

Comment: I am currently working on a database backed by a 200GB mdf file. This is not uncommon in the real world.

Comment: @Blorgbeard i almost not confused in translation with your double negative :) Thanks for the comment though

Comment: The LDF file is your database transaction log. The MDF file is the primary data file, and NDF (naming convention, I think) files are secondary data files. All databases must have one MDF file, and additional files can be created to distribute the data pages across multiple files. See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/08/15/sql-server-sql-basics-what-are-filegroups-day-9-of-10/ & http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx (or Google for "sql server file groups"). Not posting as an answer as there are far more qualified people than I who can answer this better.

Answer (score 4):

> 1 Theoretically, mdf filesize could grow to GB or perhaps TB. Is this
>   common in real world scenario?

Yes, it is common. It depends on amount of read-write operations per second and your disk subsystem. Nowadays, a database with size of hundreds GB is considered to be small.

> 2 Since MSSQL deals with single file, it would have a considerably
>   large read/write operation performed on the same file. How would this
>   impact the performance?

This is one of the most common performance bottlenecks. You need to choose appropriate disk subsystem and maybe divide your database into several filegroups and place them on different disk subsystems.

> 3 Is it possible (has there been any case) to split mdf into parts.
>   Instead of having 1 uber large mdf file, would it be better to split
>   it into chunks?

Yes you can. This "chunks" are called filegroups. You can create different tables, indexes, objects or even parts of tables in different filegroups (if version and edition of SQL-Server allows it). But it will give you advantage only if you  create filegroups across multiple disks, RAIDs and so on. For more information you can read [Using Files and Filegroups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: So @Igor (or @AnyoneReally).  Having multiple filegroups located on the same physical disk therefore has very little advantage whatsoever?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/pkcrm/archive/2009/04/25/think-spindles-not-space.aspx